# Complex Select in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

How to combine multiple rows in a table into a single row with some custom characters ?

for describe my problem I will show a sample table and data,

```
create table bar ( 
        foo text
      );

insert into bar values ('ABC'),
                       ('DEF'),
                       ('UVW'),
                       ('XYZ');
```

and I need to get a result that look like below

```
1_ABC, 2_DEF, 3_UVW, 4_XYZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result with the help of [**row_number()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) and [**string_agg**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) functions in PostgreSQL

As per Document,

> row_number() : number of the current row within its partition,
>   counting from 1
>
> string_agg(expression, delimiter): input values concatenated into a
>   string, separated by delimiter

```
select string_agg(col,', ') result 
from (
       select row_number() over() ||'_'|| foo  col 
       from bar
     ) t
```